# RewriteRule - change middle of the link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved **/news/** section of my site to **/about/news/**. Now I need to redirect old links to moved pages. I tried to use RewriteRule in .htaccess, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

RewriteRule ^$ inner.php?pathstring=/main/
RewriteRule ^(.+str=.*)$ inner.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ inner.php?path=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ about/news/$1 [R,L]
```

I post my whole .htacces here, because it was written by someone else who is unavailable now, and being a noob in php, I have some concerns that it may affect my attemts to redirect somehow.

Comment: Move it *before* your other RewriteRules. Your third one matches anything that doesn't have a `.` in it (any character that isn't an `.` matched 1 to infinity times).

Comment: Thanks I did it, but redirect still isn't happening. Maybe there's a mistake in my regex? All I get is 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(news(?:/.*)?)$ /about/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^$ inner.php?pathstring=/main/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+?str=.*)$ inner.php?path=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ inner.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your third RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ inner.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Autopsy:

- `^` - *The string **must** start with the next match*
- `([^\.]+)` - *Matches any character that isn't an `.` (which you need to escape as `.` in regex is "any character") 1 to infinity times (that's the `+`)*
- `$` - *The string **must** end with the previous match*

..so your redirect in the bottom would only work if the URL had no `.` in it, eg. `/news/blabla/mysite.html`.

How to fix it? Just move it on top of the other rules so it tries to match it first. If your change is permanent, you should also change `R` to `R=301` to make sure that it sends a `301 Moved Permanently` instead of `302 Found` (which doesn't get cached).

```
RewriteRule ^/news/(.*)$ about/news/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ inner.php?pathstring=/main/
RewriteRule ^(.+str=.*)$ inner.php?path=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ inner.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Still, redirect isn't happening. Maybe there's a mistake in my regex?